# Apply function on a pandas dataframe column which holds list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe and one of the column has a list of urls. I am trying to clean it and remove '…'

I have about 4.65 million records and would like to perform this function as efficiently as possible.

Input:

```
1                                         []
2                                         []
3                          ['http://t.co…/']
4                          ['https://t.co/']
5                          ['http://t.co/…']
6                          ['http://t.co/…']
7              ['http://t.co/', 'http://t…']
8                   ['http://facebook.com/']

Name: urls, Length: 100, dtype: object
```

Output:

```
 1                                         []
 2                                         []
 3                          ['http://t.co/']
 4                          ['https://t.co/']
 5                          ['http://t.co/']
 6                          ['http://t.co/']
 7              ['http://t.co/', 'http://t']
 8                   ['http://facebook.com/']

Name: urls, Length: 100, dtype: object
```

Comment: Please share a sample of your dataframe.

Comment: And another one with your desired output

Answer (score 0):

Data1['urls']=Data1['urls'].apply(lambda row: [i.replace('…', ' ') for i in row])